# Addressing 'This async method lacks 'await' operators' warning in overriding method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

I have a method in my base class with the following signature.

```
public virtual async Task<TagBuilder> RenderAsync(int columnWidth)
{
    // ...
}
```

This works fine, but I have a lot of derived classes that override this method. And some of those overrides do not use `await`.

This gives me a warning.

> Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

What is the best way to address this warning? First off, I don't want warnings all over my code. But I need `async` in the base class. And I want to address this in a sanctioned way that doesn't introduce any unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Do you really need to make the base method `async`?

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin: How else can I call async methods from it?

Comment: The base method does not have to be `async`. To make it awaitable, it is sufficient to make it `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin: Why wouldn't I want it async? That frees up the processor while the method is waiting on longer running tasks. I'm not clear what you are wanting to accomplish.

Comment: @JonathanWood As the warning is telling you, your method is in fact synchronous.  It is not freeing up anything to do anything.  That you think that marking the method `async` makes it asynchronous, despite their being no awaits, is exactly why this warning exists to make sure you know that's not the case.

Comment: @Servy: I don't think you read the question. The base method is indeed asynchronous and has await. It's the overriding methods that cause the warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove `async` from your derived classes and return a value using `Task.FromResult()`

Base:

```cs
public virtual async Task<TagBuilder> RenderAsync(int columnWidth)
{
    // ...
}
```

Derived:

```cs
public override Task<TagBuilder> RenderAsync(int columnWidth)
{
    TagBuilder tag = GetTag();
    return Task.FromResult(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The `async` is an implementation detail and is not part of the method signature. `async` is only required when the method uses `await`. Virtual or abstract base methods and overriding methods can differ in this respect.

For the same reason, you cannot apply `async` to methods in interfaces.

You can return `Task.FromResult(someTagBuilder)` without `async` and without `await` in one method and use `async`/`await` in the other one.

Comment: While the accepted answer gets the job done, I think this answer is better. The crucial point is that `async` is an implementation detail and is not part of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain my intention with a simplified and compiling code example. Consider these classes:

```cs
class Base
{
    public virtual Task<TagBuilder> RenderAsync(int columnWidth)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new TagBuilder { Name = "Base" });
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
    public override async Task<TagBuilder> RenderAsync(int columnWidth)
    {
        // Method is async and uses await
        return await Task.FromResult(new TagBuilder { Name = "Derived1" });
    }
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
    public override Task<TagBuilder> RenderAsync(int columnWidth)
    {
        // Method is not async and no await
        return Task.FromResult(new TagBuilder { Name = "Derived2" });
    }
}

class TagBuilder
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can still `await` `Derived2.RenderAsync()` *even if it is not async* and no compiler warnings will be emitted anywhere:

```cs
var derived2 = new Derived2();
await derived2.RenderAsync(1);
```

This example shows that the base method *does not have to be* `async`. You can have some of the overriden methods with or without `async` and still can *call* all of them (base and derived methods) using `await`.

The bottom line is that to make a method awaitable, it is sufficient to make it `Task` or `Task<T>`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The goal is to use `await` in the base class, but not in the derived class. You seem to have it the other way around. The accepted answer seems exactly what I was looking for.